# How to add multiple view controller in a page controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I want to add multiple view controller in a page controller so that view controller can scroll left and right side in page view controller.

How to do like this..?

Comment: this  helps you ... http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the UIPageViewControllerDataSource. All the documentation is found here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDataSourceProtocolRef/index.html

In the

```
pageViewController:viewControllerBeforeViewController:
pageViewController:viewControllerAfterViewController:
```

methods you return the UIViewControllers you want to show.

With the

```
setViewControllers:direction:animated:completion:
```

method from the UIPageViewController you can set the initial UIViewController.

Comment: Jan thanks for the details,Do you have a sample code, if yes please share with me.I have tried using delegate methods but its not working for me.

Comment: There are enough tutorials online. Like the one Suraj Sukale recommended you: http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/